# Every activity in my app is added to app drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

Well, just like the title suggests, every activity within my application is being added to the app drawer.... Im really hating this new ADT. First it was a problem with the app name appearing as the first activity name, now all the activities are showing up on the application list. If I go to uninstall it only shows 1. Anyone else having this problem and has figured out a work around?

Answer (score 4):

for future cases specifically you can change in the android manifest under :

```
<intent-filter>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

change to:

```
<intent-filter>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

This will remove the activities' icon from the app drawer. As the OP says: sometimes the wizard puts this in the manifest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out... Everytime you create a new activity through the adt wizard (New -> Android Activity) it creates the code in your manifest for you.... the problem is that it added intent filters to it as well. Just remove those and they dont show up.... stupid adt.

Answer (score 0):

I know when I am using IntelliJ as my IDE for Android programming, there is a box you can check when using the wizard to create a new Activity that says "Mark as start-up Activity".

Be aware of these types of things because that is what caused me to have the same problem you had Shaun.

I wouldn't completely erase the intent filters, simply have only the Activity you want as the "start-up" Activity marked as the "Launcher" in the Manifest file. All other Activities get "Default".